# How to use and operator in mongodb for same field in php

Tags: php, mongodb, using

How to use equal and not equal for the same field in MongoDB using PHP
and how to use the and operator in MongoDB?

For example the MySQL query is like:

```
select * 
from 
table 
where 
skills = .net 
and 
skills != networking
```

Comment: [MongoDB $and operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) ?

Comment: Depends on how your documents look. Show us a sample doc. and the query you are working on

Comment: What? if skill = .net how can it be networking?

Comment: They are mutually exclusive by default ryt, since you are using = operator? ryt?